# JSON Serialization in C

Tags: c, utf-8, json

What is the best way to generate UTF-8 JSON in C? I've looked at [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/), but it seems extremely bulky. Is there any other good low-dependency library for creating and reading JSON objects/strings in C?

Comment: What is wrong with Jansson? Seems like perfectly usable C library to me

Comment: It has a bunch of dependencies and my boss would rather not have to worry about them. *I* would be ok with using it, I'm just looking for alternatives first.

Comment: Look at the list for C at http://json.org/.

Comment: @Peter Downs: It's time for your boss to retire.

Comment: @Peter: I'm not familiar with Jansson, but the docs claim that it has no dependencies - it even documents how to avoid using autotools if you can't use that.

Comment: Jansson has zero dependencies.  I'm using it on a project right now, you run automake, `#include <jansson.h>` in your source, read the great [documentation](http://www.digip.org/jansson/doc/2.2/apiref.html), and you're set.

Comment: Jansson depends on autoconf and supplies a minimal libtool that works but is not entirely portable, Does not provide flexible testing for -shared forms in configure.ac (as in depends on gcc), It does fail its first API test on big-endian ia64 and x86, so I am skeptical of this library. Raise issue #606 on GitHub.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perhaps the JSON module from CCAN?  http://ccodearchive.net/ It doesn't even depend on anything else from CCAN, and consists of exactly two files `json.c` and `json.h`

(The JSON module is here http://git.ozlabs.org/?p=ccan;a=tree;f=ccan/json )

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. A million thanks!

Comment: Just following up in case anyone else sees this. The JSON CCAN module is awesome: fully functional but simple enough that I was able to add a few extensions. Very clean, and the source code is well documented and formatted.

Comment: this code uses snprintf.  the WIN32 and the linux versions of this are NOT identical.

Comment: It also uses GOTOS?!  "Very clean" for sufficiently heretical values of clean.

Comment: @MarkStorer It uses them for failure handling, which is a common pattern, and none of the destinations are more than a slight scroll away from the jump. goto is not as evil as everyone says see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful If goto results in simpler control flow than the alternative that's good, it's easier to reason about. The harm is when the goto makes the code harder to understand.

Comment: I wasn't speaking of some failure of logic.  There are perfectly valid reasons for using gotos in C code.  I was speaking of HERESEY, inspiring dogmatic hatred.  Quite different.  Perhaps a ";)" would have cleared things up?